# Training a small model using keras, python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new at data field and its my first project. So I downloaded facial expression data from kaggle and trying to train my model using keras tensorflow. I don't know what is issue with pandas . Although its very simple but i am unable to do it.

```
df=pd.read_csv("icml_face_data.csv")
print(df.head)

###Uptill now coding is working fine 


print(df["Usage"].colnum_features)
```

From above line its says Usage is undefined although there is a column named Usage in my .csv file

Here is a sample of `icml_face_data.csv`

```
emotion  Usage   pixels
0        Training     70 80 82 72 76 
4        Training     38 94 75 37 58
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As of now, your question does not fit the standard of a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Could you add a [minmal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as well as the full error that you encounter (in python that would mean the full Traceback). We ask that in order to be able to help you.

Comment: When i run this code its gives me an exception on "Usage" key word and up till print(df.head) its good

Comment: We don't know the structure of your csv, so it would be useful to share a sample, for example the 3 first lines. If you read [the guide that I linked in my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it states : `…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself`.

Comment: emotion  Usage  pixels
0        Training     70 80 82 72 76 80 74 82      This is the format of all records. Thanks

Comment: It is possible you have extra whitespace around the word 'Usage' so df may think the column name is say ' Usage '.  Do `print(df.columns)` to check